# Fully-independent MAMP stack on external drive?

Tags: macos, portable, mamp

More and more, I find myself needing a common environment between my work and home machines. Right now, I have two separate MAMP installs (one on each box), with the webroot symlinked to a folder on my external drive. This works pretty well, I can just plug in and go. The main complicating factor is that I have a dinky pair of `.command` files that dump and re-sync the MySQL databases manually - and if I don't remember to engage them at the end of the day, I either have to recreate the database changes from memory or I just can't work. I'm getting pretty fed up with it, there has to be a better way.

Is there any solution that would allow me to encase a MAMP stack on an external drive *and* give it single-point start and stop? I'm even willing to consider a raw build at this point, if I can get my hands on a beginner/intermediate-level guide.

What I'm looking for:

- All data and config shared between environments (from databases to virtualhosts)
- Single-point/single-click start and stop
- Default port binding (80 and 3306) - requiring admin auth is acceptable

What I've tried (and why it doesn't work):

- External host: FTP at the office is intermittent and unreliable, often unable to connect for hours. Switched to local dev with git/ssh deployment.
- [MAMP app](http://www.mamp.info/): By design, does not install onto external drives - can symlink webroot, but databases and config get left behind.
- [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp): Installs onto external drives, but does not bind lower than port 1024. The "[Install as root](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Native_Installers_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_install_the_Stack_on_OS_X_as_root.3f)" suggestion works for desktop, but breaks on external drive.
- XAMPP: Windows version can install and run from drive, but Mac version is more restricted.
- Raw Apache/PHP/MySQL: attempted recently, but couldn't figure out how to achieve single-point start/stop.

The external drive is not mandatory - if there are any other solutions that would allow me to duplicate an environment between two computers (and don't require FTP), I'm all ears. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, maybe you could install virtualbox on both home and work machines, and then have a complete LAMP stack environment that is the real thing and not having to make copies. If you must have MAMP then you can't do that, but if the ram is low then maybe try SliTaz as a linux distro within a virtualbox, I did that for my company for different reasons but it has proven useful.